# Herb garden without direct sun. Which herbs can I grow? (incl. image)

Tags: herbs, raised-beds, sunlight, shade

**What I would like to do**

I would like to create a little herb garden in a raised bed underneath the stairs which are seen in the image (shot in the evening). As there won't be any direct sun to this spot,I was wondering what I herbs still would grow. I mainly was thinking about parsly, chive, oregano, thyme, rosmarin, maybe even a small salad.

**The location**

The place you see is a litte atrium. West is behind the wall and east behind me. I'm new to this play, it might even be, that in high summer, the sun covers the whole atrium during noon. Currently the sun only reaches the right half of the atrium floor. Is this enough indirect light for herbs to grow? And what herb coud I try to grow?

[image]

Comment: Where I live that would be considered enough sunlight to grow tropical plants. It's always good to disclose the general area where you live so one can guage the environment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've always grown my herbs in full sun, so your question has forced me to branch out and learn something new :)  Here's a list (with sources) of some herbs. Fortunately, your top three choices are on the list:

From [The Spruce (whatever that is)](https://www.thespruce.com/herbs-for-a-shade-garden-1762054)

- Parsley
- Lemon balm
- Chives
- Thyme
- Mint

From [BBC Gardener's World](https://www.gardenersworld.com/plants/shade-loving-herbs-to-grow/)
Parsly, chives, and mint like in the above list, but subtract lemon balm and thyme and add:

- Dill
- Sorrel
- Chervil
- Lovage
- Coriander

From [Self-Sufficient Living](https://www.motherearthliving.com/gardening/7-herbs-that-grow-in-shade)

- Chives
- Oregano
- Parsley

This site also says that you can grow lettuce, spinach, and other greens in shade. Frankly, I'm doubtful about that.

Given this very brief survey of web sources, I'd say you'd be okay growing Chives, Parsley and Mint in your atrium. Of course, the more sun that area gets, the better your chances of success.

Answer (score 1):

That's an interesting question. I was wondering about that for a while. Having no yard where I can grow my herbs I did a research and found that the following herbs can be grown both indoor and outdoor:

1. Chicory
2. Calendula
3. Coriander

In your case if partial sublight is available, you can grow the following herbs as well:

1. Feverfew
2. Chamomile
3. Marshmallow
4. Yarrow

These plants require at least 3 hours of sunlight to be available.